# MEGA2560 only starts program after pressing RESET button multiple times

Tags: serial, interrupt, avr, uart, atmega2560

I am working on a program where I am controlling an MP3 player by using UART between my MEGA2560 and the MP3 player. The MEGA2560 sends serial commands to the MP3 player when external interrupts are generated on INT4 and INT5 and it all seems to work fine.

When I want to test my program I press the RESET button on the Arduino in order to start the program. However, sometimes the program only starts after pressing the RESET button multiple times. This happens often but not all the time, which is weird.

What do you think could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does keeping the RESET button pressed for at least 1 second change the behavior?

Comment: Are you using Serial *inside* the interrupt handlers?

Comment: What causes the signals to switch on INT4 & 5? Normally, one would have the pins connect to Gnd when a button is pressed, and the lines are held high when not pressed by a Pullup resistor, typically the internal pullup is enough. For long wires, an external pullup may be needed.

Comment: @CrossRoads
I have two sensors (one for INT4 and one for INT5). When the sensors are turned on, they send 5V on the output. I measured the output with a scope and it works.